# Was there any warrior who never used celestial wepons?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, weapon, war

We know that most of the warriors used some kind of celestial weapons i.e. astra/shastra.

Was there any warrior who fought on his own power? I mean the power created by himself and not acquired from any god or saint. I am looking examples from Mahabharata, Ramayana or puranas.

Note: Not the wars which are fought magically through power of penance.

Comment: Nearly duplicate: [Mythology war fought without any weapons?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19516/1049).

Comment: not the whole war.... just a warrior which uses his own power not on weapons or maya.

Comment: May be Jamvan...bdw what do u mean by a warrior.. soldier, Asvarohi, Gajarohi, ArdhRathi, Rathi, AtiRathi, MahaRathi, AtiMahaRathi....?

Comment: warrior means who can fight. participate in a war.

Comment: @FierceLord Then what's the point in asking this question..is it mentioned that all 18 Akshonik Soldiers used celestial weapons??... normal soldiers didn't use any celestial weapons in Mahabharata...

Comment: Ahhhh you know eklavya was he belonged to maharathi or atimaharathi i said any warrior warriors don't have classes  indovidually

Comment: In Mahabharatha, Bhima fought most wars without using any celestial powers. For example, killing Jarasandha, Bakasura, annihilating Kauravas, he used only his strength and of course some tactics of Krishna.

Answer (score 3):

It was Sri Hanuman, who never used any celestial weapons.

During the encounter with [Lankhini](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga3/sundara_3_frame.htm) or war with [demons](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga45/sundara_45_frame.htm), who attacked at the orders of Ravana or [single combat with Indrajit](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga48/sundara_48_frame.htm) or in [the war with Ravana](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga59/yuddha_59_frame.htm) in final war, Sri Hanuman fought either with fist or available steel rods or mountains or trees, etc, but not with celestial weapons.

Comment: Just curious to know if u found any celestial weapons usage by Nakula, Dusashana, Sahdeva etc. while figuring out answer for this Q...

Comment: I read somewhere so, but not sure. I have to check up.@YDS